# extracted counts matrix from Tximeta generalized experiment with no linked transcriptome are normalized?

Tags: rna-seq

I used the Tximeta vignette to construct a summarised experiment from quant files (salmon, index prepared with NCBI transcriptome).

1)Tximeta return me a non-ranged se (which I am not sure about the real implications)

because of this...
2) I used `makeLinkedTxome` to link the transcriptome and the gff (local files used in the index creation).

3)run `tximeta` on the colData to create the summarised experiment `se`

4) `seqinfo(se)` returns me a NA populated table

5) I summarise to genes (`gse`)

6) I extracted the gene counts `counts <- assay(gse)`

My questions here are;

a) Are these counts normalised? 
b) If not, how can I normalise them? TMM for example? (CalcNormFactors will not work here right?)

Is there any better way to obtain a normalised count matrix from tximeta? (maybe I don't need to link the transcriptome...)

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you! and regards,

Comment: tximeta will summarize transcript abundance estimates (or counts) to the gene level and produce raw counts. All these metadata can be used and might be useful in certain situations, but none of these are essential for the analysis. You can equivalently just use tximport to produce the same raw counts. No, counts are not normalized. TMM should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! so I can use these `counts'  with the pipeline. Perfect! thanks!!!